# VBA Copying Ranges in Multiple Sheets Member or Data Member Not Found

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to have lost my way when trying to have this script run through each of the 4 sheets.  Basically trying to copy a static range (row wise) from each of the 4 sheets listed into another range, as hardcodes depending on the user's dropdown selections (defined named of `Month1` & `Month2`).  But come along the error of

> "Data Member Not Found"

at the `sheetsArray.Cells` line.  The "Macros" sheet is where the dropdowns are stored so I believe I have to reference the defined named ranges that way?

```
Sub copyColumns()

Dim months, m1, m2, sourceSht
Dim Msg As String, Ans As Variant
Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
Dim sheetObject As Worksheet

Msg = "Are you sure you want to copy/paste over to Early Warning?"

Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)

Select Case Ans

    Case vbYes

    months = Split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", ",")
    Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("HRM", "SRM", "NRM", "Corp"))
    Set sourceSht = Worksheets("Macros")


    m1 = Application.Match(sourceSht.Range("Month1").Value, months, 0)
    m2 = Application.Match(sourceSht.Range("Month2").Value, months, 0)

    For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray

    sheetsArray.Range(sheetsArray.Cells(35, 4 + m1), sheetsArray.Cells(376, 4 + m2)).Copy
    sheetsArray.Range(sheetsArray.Cells(35, 17 + m1), sheetsArray.Cells(376, 17 + m2)).PasteSpecial xlValues

    Next sheetObject

    Case vbNo
    GoTo Quit:

End Select

Quit:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning try to redeclare `SheetsArray` as `Variant` and give it some values:

```
Dim sheetObject As Variant
Dim sheetsArray As Variant
sheetsArray = Array("HRM", "SRM", "NRM", "Corp")
```

Delete this line:

```
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("HRM", "SRM", "NRM", "Corp"))
```

Then change this:

```
sheetsArray.Range(sheetsArray.Cells(35, 4 + m1), sheetsArray.Cells(376, 4 + m2)).Copy
```

To this:

```
With worksheets(sheetobject)
    .Range(.Cells(35, 4 + m1), .Cells(376, 4 + m2)).Copy
End With
```

Comment: Gives a "424 Object Required" error where "For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray" is.

Comment: `Dim sheetObject As Variant`, @AspiringDeveloper

Answer (score 1):

simply change the two lines in the loop to

```
For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
    with sheetObject
    .Range(.Cells(35, 4 + m1), .Cells(376, 4 + m2)).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(35, 17 + m1), .Cells(376, 17 + m2)).PasteSpecial xlValues
    end with
Next sheetObject
```

Comment: Still seem to encounter the same error using this method.

Comment: Sorry, while typing my answer I received a call and didn't double check it. I have edited my answer